# ERROR Error when sending message to topic

Tags: apache-kafka

While producing message in kafka, i am getting the following error :

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic nil_PF1_P1
hi
hello

[2016-07-19 17:06:34,542] ERROR Error when sending message to topic nil_PF1_P1 with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
[2016-07-19 17:07:34,544] ERROR Error when sending message to topic nil_PF1_P1 with key: null, value: 5 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.


$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic nil_PF1_P1
Topic:nil_PF1_P1    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: nil_PF1_P1   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
```

Any idea on this??

Comment: Can you post the results of following command `bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic nil_PF1_P1`

Comment: Reposted after edition!!

Comment: It seems everything is good from zk end. It seems there is problem with Kafka broker bind address and port! Can you check whether your kafka is reachable at localhost:9092?

Comment: btw what version of Kafka are you using? if it is 0.9 or later are you configured it with ssl? if then you need to provide ssl info while producing and consuming!

Comment: yes it is 0.10.0.0 . what is ssl ? Can explain briefly. A link will also do!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can read about ssl in kafka [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security). It is used to make your kafka cluster more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the link..but i hope there is no change of producer consumer command line utilities with change of version!!

Comment: Actually it matters when you use SSL! What have you configured for `listeners` in broker.properties files?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of changing `server.properties` include the address `0.0.0.0` in the code itself.
Instead of

```
/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list Hostname:9092 --topic MyFirstTopic1
```

use

```
/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list 0.0.0.0:9092 --topic MyFirstTopic1
```

Answer (score 17):

It may be because of some parameters from Kafka's `server.properties` file. You can find more information [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Ingestion-Integration/Error-when-sending-message-to-topic-in-Kafka/td-p/41440)

1. Stop the Kafka server with

   ```
   cd $KAFKA_HOME/bin  
   ./kafka-server-stop.sh
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   listeners=PLAINTEXT://hostname:9092
   ```

   to

   listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

   in `$KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties`
3. Restart the Kafka server with

   ```
   $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties
   ```

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old but this may work for someone else who's dealing with it:
I changed 2 things:
 1. change the **"bootstrap.servers"** property or the **--broker-list** option to **0.0.0.0:9092**
 2. change (uncomment and edit in my case) the server.properties in 2 properties

- listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092 to **listeners=PLAINTEXT://:909**2
- advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092 to **advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092**

Comment: `0.0.0.0` was the main solution because `localhost` is `127.0.0.1` so how'd it work?

Comment: No that's not where the solution lies, it just that you need to configure the endpoint of the service properly on the server side by changing the properties I mentioned otherwise it will give you the default local ipv4 address returned from  `java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()`
so just to make sure you use any local ipv4 adress you can use 0.0.0.0 but you can also use 127.0.0.1 after configuring properly

Comment: are you saying `0.0.0.` is working due to some other issue?

Comment: in my case it was easy it was bound to ipv6 by default so just a note there - make sure it's running on ipv4 addy and disable the ipv6 if it's not needed

Answer (score 10):

I faced similar problem, where I was able to produce and consume on `localhost` but not from different machines on network. Based few answers I got the clue that essentially we need to expose `advertised.listener` to producer and consumer, however giving 0.0.0.0 was also not working. So gave exact IP against `advertised.listeners`

`advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://HOST.IP:9092`

And I left `listener=PLAINTEXT://:9092` as it is.

So with this the spark exposes advertised ip and port to producers and consumers

Comment: You are right, You need to expose `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://HOST.IP:9092` if you want to produce or consume from different machines

Comment: Thanks, you save me a lot of headache! Why didn't it work when I also set listener to HOST.IP I don't get it.

Comment: Worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you are running **hortonworks** cluster, check the listening port in ambari.

In my case **9092 was not my port**. I went to ambari and found the **listening port was set to 6667**
it worked for me. **:)**

Comment: i know u might have done for reason, soon u will fix the issue and update the code and hfd

Answer (score 4):

I get the same error today with `confluent_kafka 0.9.2 (0x90200)` and `librdkafka 0.9.2 (0x90401)`. In my case, I specified the wrong broker port in [tutorialpoints](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_basic_operations.htm) example:

```
$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic tutorialpoint-basic-ops-01
```

although my broker was started on port **9094**:

```
$ cat server-02.properties 
broker.id=2
port=9094
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-example-logs-02
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
```

Although the **9092** port was not open (`netstat -tunap`), it took 60s for `kafka-console-producer.sh` to raise an error. Looks like this tool needs a fix to:

- fail faster
- with a more explicit error message.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the above exception stacktrace. I investigated and found the root cause.I faced it when I established Kafka cluster with two nodes.With the following settings in server.properties.Here I am denoting server.properties of kafka node 1 and 2 as broker1.properties and broker2.properties

broker1.properties settings

```
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://A.B.C.D:9092
    zookeeper.connect=A.B.C.D:2181,E.F.G.H:2181
```

broker2.properties settings

```
    listeners=PLAINTEXT://E.F.G.H:9092
    zookeeper.connect=A.B.C.D:2181,E.F.G.H:2181
```

I was trying to start a producer from node1 or from node2 using the following command:
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic OUR_TOPIC
and I was getting the above timeout exception stacktrace although Kafka is running in both machine.

Although producer is starting either from Leader node or from a follower I was always getting the same.

While using below command from any broker I was able to get producer the message.

```
   ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list A.B.C.D:9092 --topic OUR_TOPIC
    or
   ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list E.F.G.H:9092 --topic OUR_TOPIC
   or
   ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list A.B.C.D:9092,E.F.G.H:9092 --topic OUR_TOPIC
```

So the root cause is that Kafka broker internally using listeners=PLAINTEXT://E.F.G.H:9092 property while staring a producer.This property must match to start a kafka broker from any of the node while starting a producer.Converting this property to listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 will work for our very first command.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue:
Using Hortonworks HDP 2.5. 
Kerberisation enabled

Fixed by providing the correct security protocol and ports.
**Example commands:**

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list sand01.intranet:6667, san02.intranet:6667, san03.intranet:6667--topic test--security-protocol PLAINTEXTSASL


./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper sand01:2181 --topic test--from-beginning --security-protocol PLAINTEXTSASL
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I am using Kafka docker with Openshift. I was getting the same problem. It got fixed when I passed the environment variable `KAFKA_LISTENERS` with a value of `PLAINTEXT://:9092`. This will eventually add create an entry `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092` under *server.properties*.

The listeners doesn't have to have a hostname.

Answer (score 2):

Another scenario here. No clue on what was happening till I find a kafka log with the following message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version for API key 3: 2
```

Apparently the producer was using a newer kafka-client (java) than the kafka server and the API used was invalid (client using 1.1 and server on 10.0). On the Client/Producer I got the:

```
Error producing to topic Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

For Apache Kafka v2.11-1.1.0

Start zookeeper server:

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Start kafka server:

```
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Create one topic name "my_topic":

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic my_topic --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

Start the producer:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my_topic
```

Start the consumer:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my_topic --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Apache Kafka on a Hortonworks (HDP 2.X release) installation. The error message encountered means that Kafka producer was not able to push the data to the segment log file. From a command-line console, that would mean 2 things :

1. You are using incorrect port for the brokers
2. Your listener config in server.properties are not working

If you encounter the error message while writing via scala api, additionally check connection to kafka cluster using `telnet <cluster-host> <broker-port>`

**NOTE:** If you are using scala api to create topic, it takes sometime for the brokers to know about the newly created topic. So, immediately after topic creation, the producers might fail with the error `Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.`

I did the following checks in order to resolve this issue:

The first difference once I check via Ambari is that Kafka brokers listen on port `6667` on HDP 2.x (apache kafka uses 9092).

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:6667
```

Next, use the ip instead of localhost.
I executed `netstat -na | grep 6667`

```
tcp        0      0 192.30.1.5:6667        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        1      0 192.30.1.5:52242       192.30.1.5:6667        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 192.30.1.5:54454       192.30.1.5:6667        TIME_WAIT
```

So, I modified the producer call to user the IP and not localhost:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.30.1.5:6667 --topic rdl_test_2
```

To monitor if you have new records being written, monitor the `/kafka-logs` folder.

```
cd /kafka-logs/<topic name>/
ls -lart
-rw-r--r--.  1 kafka hadoop        0 Feb 10 07:24 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r--.  1 kafka hadoop 10485756 Feb 10 07:24 00000000000000000000.timeindex
-rw-r--r--.  1 kafka hadoop 10485760 Feb 10 07:24 00000000000000000000.index
```

Once, the producer successfully writes, the segment log-file `00000000000000000000.log` will grow in size.

See the size below:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 kafka hadoop 10485760 Feb 10 07:24 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r--. 1 kafka hadoop       **45** Feb 10 09:16 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 kafka hadoop 10485756 Feb 10 07:24 00000000000000000000.timeindex
```

At this point, you can run the consumer-console.sh:

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.30.1.5:6667 --topic rdl_test_2 --from-beginning
response is hello world
```

After this step, if you want to produce messages via the Scala API's , then change the `listeners` value(from localhost to a public IP) and restart Kafka brokers via Ambari:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.30.1.5:6667
```

A Sample producer will be as follows:

```
package com.scalakafka.sample
import java.util.Properties
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{ProducerRecord, KafkaProducer}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{StringSerializer, StringDeserializer}

class SampleKafkaProducer {
  case class KafkaProducerConfigs(brokerList: String = "192.30.1.5:6667") {
    val properties = new Properties()
    val batchsize :java.lang.Integer = 1

    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", brokerList)
    properties.put("key.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer])
    properties.put("value.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer])
    //    properties.put("serializer.class", classOf[StringDeserializer])
        properties.put("batch.size", batchsize)
    //    properties.put("linger.ms", 1)
    //    properties.put("buffer.memory", 33554432)
  }

  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](KafkaProducerConfigs().properties)

  def produce(topic: String, messages: Iterable[String]): Unit = {
    messages.foreach { m =>
      println(s"Sending $topic and message is $m")
      val result = producer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, m)).get()
      println(s"the write status is ${result}")
    }
    producer.flush()
    producer.close(10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

adding such a line after the topic helped with the same issue:
... --topic XXX **--property "parse.key = true" --property "key.separator =:"**

Hope this helps someone.